# Entering SQL table values not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CustomerFName, CustomerLName, DateOfTravel, TravelLocation, AgencyID)
 VALUES ('Jake' 'Bob' 'John' 'Phillip' 'Claire' 'Jenny' 'Amy' 'Gerlad' 'Jessica' 'Fredrick' 'Ray' 'Selena',
'Fallas' 'Kroger' 'Nike' 'Wayne' 'Finny' 'Highland' 'Shwank' 'Hemway' 'Phillips' 'Kanes' 'Stacks' 'Gomez',
'02-10-2010' '02-10-2010' '01-16-2010' '01-16-2010' '03-12-2010' '03-12-2010' '04-19-2010' '04-19-2010' '05-21-2010' '05-21-2010' '06-02-2010' '06-02-2010',
 'Raleigh,NC and Denver,CO' 'Raleigh,NC and Denver,CO' 'Los Angeles,CA and 
  Phoenix,AZ' 'Los Angeles,CA and Phoenix,AZ' 'Los Angeles,CA and  
  Phoenix,AZ' 'Los Angeles,CA and Phoenix,AZ' 'Los Angeles,CA and 
  Phoenix,AZ' 'Los Angeles,CA and Phoenix,AZ' 'Los Angeles,CA and 
  Phoenix,AZ' 'Los Angeles,CA and Phoenix,AZ' 'Detroit,MI and Atlanta,GA'  
  'Detroit,MI and Atlanta,GA'
 )
```

Error message is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Bob'.

Comment: You need commas between your values.

Comment: You also need to have sets of values matching the order of the actual fields. Not all `CustomerID`s followed by all `CustomerFName`s.

Comment: even if -----'Jake' 'Bob' 'John' 'Phillip' 'Claire' 'Jenny' 'Amy' 'Gerlad' 'Jessica' 'Fredrick' 'Ray' 'Selena'     , belong in the same column---CustomerFName??? i thought commans were used to separate---- CustomerFName from values contained in the next column listed... in this case the next would be CustomerLName , thanks for the feedback

Comment: i tried comma separating and got:

Comment: Msg 110, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

Comment: Try treating them each as unique sets of data `...VALUES('Jake', '02-10-2010', 'Raleigh,NC and Denver,CO'), ('Bob', '02-10-2010', 'Raleigh,NC and Denver,CO')...`

Comment: Your column list and the values do not lined up. I believe you are trying to use table value constructor to insert multiple records in one statement. The link will make everything more clearer. =)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to insert data by column, and you need to insert it by row. Also, you are missing commas between each value. You need to do something like this:

```
 INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerFName,CustomerLName,DateOfTravel,TravelLocation) 
 VALUES('Jake', 'Fallas', '02-10-2010', 'Raleigh,NC and Denver,CO')
```

Except for a big problem here is that you haven't provided a CustomerID OR AgencyID values. You will note I left those columns out of the query above. If you include those columns in your INSERT, but no associated VALUES, you will get an error. It is probable that your table auto increments the CustomerID, which would be auto generated on insert, but maybe not. As for the AgencyID, it probably references another table and you will need to get those values if you want to maintain integrity. You may not even be able to perform the insert without a valid AgencyID if that field is required (NOT NULL).